# Is the a way to @autowire the real service with Mockito and still get @Value properties

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spy

Using Mockito

We have this type of service that get the "regexPattern" value from application.yml or gets the default value if it is not defined

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class EmailValidationService {

    @Value("${validators.emailValidator.regexPattern:'"+ DefaultEmailValidator.DEFAULT_PATTERN  + "'}")
    private String regexPattern;

    public EmailValidator getEmailValidator(){
        return new DefaultEmailValidator(regexPattern);
    }
}
```

When using Mockito we want to use this service (the real service) and not mock it
so we use:

```
 @Spy
    private EmailValidationService emailValidationService = new EmailValidationService();
```

But the "regexPattern" variable always gets null value and not the default value

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) instead of a `@Spy` in your test:

```java
@SpyBean
private EmailValidationService emailValidationService;
```

For this you'll need a `spring-boot-test` dependency and make sure your test is run with Spring runner:

> If you are using JUnit 4, do not forget to also add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there is no need to add the equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and the other @…​Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Another alternative is to explicitly set the field value in your Spy:

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(emailValidationService, "regexPattern", DefaultEmailValidator.DEFAULT_PATTERN);
```

Comment: We use this @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) , is there some equivalent for that?

Comment: MockitoJUnitRunner is not Spring aware - it doesn't know anything about those `@Value` annotations, so with simple `@Spy` it's not possible to inject a value automagically this way. On the other hand I don't see any reason not to use the Spring runner if you use Spring Boot in your project.